# Display a day of week in text in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

This query displays count Actions grouped by day of the week.

```sql
select count(*) c, 
date_part('dow', "updatedAt"  at time zone 'Europe/Paris') dow
from "Action" date_part('dow', "updatedAt"  at time zone 'Europe/Paris')
```

Days are displayed as number. Is there a way to display it as text? Does PostgreSQL has such a function?

Comment: Can you try `select count(*) c, 
to_char(date_trunc('day', "updatedAt" at time zone 'Europe/Paris'), 'Day') dow
`

Comment: Use to_char() and the layout you like. Usually this is done in the presentation layer of the application, not in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [to_char()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) to format a date or timestamp value as text. You can use [`Day`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE) to display the day's name (e.g. Tuesday)

```
select count(*) c, 
       to_char("updatedAt"  at time zone 'Europe/Paris', 'Day') dow
from "Action" 
group by to_char("updatedAt"  at time zone 'Europe/Paris', 'Day')
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you want text format use `::TEXT` at the end. in future you can use other like `::DATE`, `::TIMESTAMP`, `::DECIMAL`...

`date_part('dow', "updatedAt"  at time zone 'Europe/Paris')::TEXT dow`